# I use django and mysql, but the time is wrong when I use DateTimeField

Tags: mysql, django, datetime

I have two models `A` and `B`, `B` is a foreign key in `A` and `B` has a `DateTimeField`.

In a function in `A`, I get a time:

```
time_temp=timezone.now()
```

then after some code, I use it like:

```
self.B.time=time_temp,
```

then I save it like

```
self.B.save(),
```

but the time in mysql in `B` always wrong, a little later then time_temp, I don't know why, I need your help

Comment: I think its not the problem of UTC, it's just 5 minutes later, something like the self.B.time is not the time_temp, but the time when it excutes

Answer (score 0):

Django converts time to UTC before passing it to MySQL when `USE_TZ` is set to `true`.

Comment: I think its not the problem of UTC, it's just 5 minutes later, something like the self.B.time is not the time_temp, but the time when it excutes

Answer (score 0):

I often have the case in which my datetimes are 1 hour after my timezone (BST).
To sort it out I set USE_TZ to true in the settings and the timezone to my timezone... I wonder if you're having a similar issue?

Comment: I think its not the problem of UTC, it's just 5 minutes later, something like the self.B.time is not the time_temp, but the time when it excutes